How to run a executable in GPU(NVIDIA)?
I want to run a Game executable file in GPU but instead it runs on CPU. How to run it in GPU?
*The game is not installed. It is a folder where I run the executable FILE.
os- pop!-os (gnome)
cpu - amd ryzen 5 4000series
GPU - NVIDIA gtx 1650
game - cities:skyline
16 gigs of RAM
Discrete graphic card option
I get this option for installed apps but how to get it for executable files.

I just realized you said you are using pop OS.  This may be different for pop OS in ways I don't know, this is generally why this site is strictly only for Ubuntu questions.

I thought pop os based on ubuntu so it would be the same.

It might be the same, but it may not.  For example, Mint is based on Ubuntu but changes up the mechanism for installing additional drivers (which I realized may not be your problem after all).  And, regardless it's the policy of the site, intended to cut down on potential confusion.

@thomasrutter I have started a question in Unix&Linux. Thanks for the input. I am new to forum systems.
